# To show that $\exp(\psi(2n+1))\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n dx$ is a positive integer, where $\psi(x)$ is the Chebyshev function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, beta-function

I have to show that $$\exp(\psi(2n+1))\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n dx \ \in \mathbb{N}$$
where $\psi(x)$ is the Chebyshev function, and $0 \leq x \leq 1$

The Chebyshev function is defined as the following:
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{p^{\alpha}\leq x}\log p$$

For instance, when $n=3$ we have
$$\exp(\psi(7)) = \prod_{p^{\alpha}\leq x}p=2\cdot3\cdot 2\cdot5\cdot7$$
$$\int_0^1 x^3 (1-x)^3 \ dx = \frac{1}{140}$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot 2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot\frac{1}{140} =3$$

Comment: you should include also $2^2$, then it is not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I realise that. But why should I? The definition of the Chebyshev function says that the summand should be primes, but not prime powers. But the sum is over prime powers.

Comment: So for each prime power, you add the log of that prime. Therefore, the product is $2\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 7$, with the second $2$ coming from $2^2=4$

Comment: Ah! Right, I was right. I was misinterpreting the Chebyshev function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a copy of Ram Murty's $\textit{Problems in Analytic Number Theory}$, 2nd Edition, it's exercise 3.1.4.

Show that $e^{\psi(n)}=\text{lcm}\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.

Show that $I_n=\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n\ dx\leq 2^{-2n}$.

Show that $I_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_0^1(-1)^k{n\choose k}x^{n+k}\ dx$ and that $I_n\times\text{lcm}\{1,2,\cdots,2n+1\}$ is a positive integer.

Think you can take it from there?